# JQGrid local search multiple columns

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid with local search (inside the columns header).

I have 2 columns that I want to merge the search for them - 
so, when I write a value inside the search input this value will be searched in 2 columns at the same time.

Is it possible to implement this? and if so,  HOW ??

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) for searching in a grid which has `datatype: "local"`. In the case jqGrid fills `postData.filters` parameter in the form described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options), which corresponds searching via dialog with `multipleSearch: true`.

You can implement your requirements inside of `beforeSearch` callback of `filterToolbar` method. Inside of the callback you can use

```js
var postData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
```

to get the reference on `postData` object. Then you can use `JSON.parse(postData.filters)` to convert filter created by `filterToolbar` to object. It will be object like

```json
{
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules": [{
        "field": "someColumnName",
        "op": "cn",
        "data": "data entered by user"
    }]
}
```

You can modify the object by adding one more item in `"rules"` and setting `postData.filters` to new value `JSON.stringify(modifiedFiltersObject)`. Finally `beforeSearch` callback should return `false` to continue filtering. In the way, you will be able implement your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102666),  you can use filterInput method. This method allow to search on all fields in grid data using single input value. Here is [description of the method](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#search-all-fields)

Here is a [demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/searching/search_all/index.html)